# Without using any number write a code in python to print number from 61 to 70

Tags: python

How can i print numbers from 61 to 70 in python without using any number in my code . Also I don't know the ascii character corresponding to 61 and 70 .

Comment: Ok, that's a statement, not a question. What did you come up with?

Comment: Did you use ASCII?

Comment: I thought this could be possible with ascii value but little bit of confused how to deal with that

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to loop over the `ord` of the corresponding ascii characters

```
for num in range(ord('='), ord('F')):
    print(num)
```

Output

```
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
```

This works by essentially looking up which characters correspond to `61` and `70` then using those to loop over

```
>>> chr(61)
'='
>>> chr(70)
'F'
```

Comment: what if i don't remember the ascii value corresponding to 61 and 70

Comment: You can use `chr` as I demonstrated at the bottom of my answer

Comment: beat me to it :) have this typed up ready to post, gj!

Comment: i was asked not to use any number and i don't remember the ascii values and I can't use chr(61) since this contain number 61 @CoryKramer